# History.js + urls in HTML4 browsers

Tags: jquery, history.js

i'm trying to implement History.js and it works the only problem i'm having is with the urls in HTML4 browsers.

The url of the page where i'm using History.js is the following:

http://mywebsite.com/en/foo/bar/

On this page i'm using History.js to submit forms, so the state i'm pushing is a query string:
?name=value&name2=value2 ..

In a HTML5 enabled browser this results in urls as this:

http://mywebsite.com/en/foo/bar/?name=value&name2=value2

Which is ok, but in a HTML4 enabled browser i'm getting this:

http://mywebsite.com/en/foo/bar#bar/?name=value&name2=value2

I really hate it that 'bar' is added to the url 2 times, it should only be in front of the hash sign. I tried looking in the code to find the reason for this, but i was unable to find it. Any idea why this is, and how to fix this?

Kind regards,

Daan

Comment: not sure what the problem is, does it not actually function? or is this a purely 'preference' thing?

Comment: Thank you for your response, .. it's a preference thing i was wondering if there is an option to remove the duplication 'bar#bar?' to just 'bar#?' ? The examples on the github page show this for HTML4 browsers: www.mysite.com/#?state=4 no duplication .. but this is probably because it's at the root?